# How to show popup view that can be dragged to close and can show other popup over it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to develop a pop up comments view which can be closed by dragging down or right and a like view which can be open from comment view and always remains top of comment view. Screenshots are attached.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Material Dialogs Library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).It is an easy-to-use and customizable dialogs API, enabling you to use Material designed dialogs down to API 8. You can also implement custom views easily using this library.